# Scrollify.js add class on current section

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollify

Am trying to add something like 'active' class on to the current section in a page using scrollify.js.

Am able to get the index value, but not the section id or section class! How to get current section's id or class.

Here is the sample code I tried to achieve.

```
<section id="first" data-section="first" class="scroll-section"> </section>

before:function(index, sections) {
    alert(index);
},
```

This return index value. I am trying to get the section id **first**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `$.scrollify.current()` it returns the current section.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <html>
    <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="jquery.scrollify.js"></script>
          <style>
          .sectioncolor {
          background-color: black;
          }
          </style>
      <script>
        $(function() {

          $.scrollify({
            section : ".section-class-name",
            sectionName : "section-name",
            before:function(index, sections) {
            var sno = index+1;
            $(".section-class-name").removeClass("sectioncolor");
            $(".section-class-name:nth-child("+sno+")").addClass("sectioncolor");
            },
            after:function(index, sections) {
            var sno = index+1;
            $(".section-class-name").removeClass("sectioncolor");
            $(".section-class-name:nth-child("+sno+")").addClass("sectioncolor");


            },
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="section-class-name" data-section-name="home" style="height:500px;border:1px solid red;"></div>
      <div class="section-class-name" data-section-name="about" style="height:500px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I hope this example will help you